# Get empty array after For inside the callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I try to store the result of a DB query in an array but I always got an empty array. I don't understand very well how Async works but I think this code should be work because I store The variable before It finish

**Note:** following is an array also.

code:

```
    exports.getfollowingUser = function(req, res){
  followedUser=[];
  following = req.user.follow;

  for (i = 0; i < following.length; i++) { 
    User.find(following[i].followed, function (err, followUser){
    followedUser[i]= followUser;
    });
    }
    console.log(followedUser) // result empty
    res.render('following', {
      followedUser: followedUser 
    });
  };
```

Comment: JohnnyHK could you explain me please ?

Comment: There are great answers in the linked duplicate that describe the issue in detail. In short, your `for` loop completes and the code continues on to the `console.log` line before any of the `user.find` callbacks occur so `followedUser` isn't modified yet. Your confusion is natural, as async is hard to wrap your head around. Take some time to read and understand those answers, it should really help.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I read the other answer but i can't get it because i don't know other way to store the data :S